# Failing to fetch CategorizedFacebookType

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I have an application which I developed about a year ago and I'm
fetching facebook accounts like this:

```
facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(access_token);
Connection<CategorizedFacebookType> con = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/accounts", CategorizedFacebookType.class);
fbAccounts = con.getData();
```

It worked fine until about a month ago, but now it returns the
fbAccounts list empty. Why is that?

I was hoping moving from restfb-1.6.2.jar to restfb-1.6.9.jar would
help but no luck, it comes up empty on both.

What am I missing?

EDIT, to provide the code for another error I have with this API. The following code used to work:

```
String id = page.getFbPageID(); // (a valid facebook page id)
FBInsightsDaily daily = new FBInsightsDaily(); // an object holding some insights values

try {
    Parameter param = Parameter.with("asdf", "asdf"); // seems like the param is required
    JsonObject allValues = facebookClient.executeMultiquery(createQueries(date, id), JsonObject.class, param);
    daily.setPageActiveUsersDaily((Integer)(((JsonArray)allValues.opt("page_active_users_daily")).getJsonObject(0)).opt("value"));
    ...
```

This throws the following exception:

```
com.restfb.json.JsonException: JsonArray[0] not found.
at com.restfb.json.JsonArray.get(JsonArray.java:252)
at com.restfb.json.JsonArray.getJsonObject(JsonArray.java:341)
```

Again, this used to work fine but now throws this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `manage_pages` permission from the user to access their list of adminned pages - a year ago I'm not sure you did - check that you're obtaining that permission from your users

{edit}
Some of the insights metrics were also deprecated, the specific values you're checking may no longer exist - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/ should have the details of what is available now

Try to check your queries manually in the [Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to eliminate any issues in your code and hopefully get more detailed error messages that your SDK may be swallowing

Comment: Any other changes I should know of? Looks like this: JsonObject allValues = facebookClient.executeMultiquery(createQueries(date, id), JsonObject.class, param); doesn't work as well.

Comment: It's not clear what API call that is you're making or what the error is from that :/

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, Igy. I edited the question to provide more info.